# Construct object array with no input arguments

Tags: arrays, matlab, object, constructor, superclass

## Background

I have different types of files that I extract from and store data in, for example .csv and database files. They are usually large files and I already have appropriate methods for extracting data from them.

## Desired behaviour

Let's use the class `textfile` as an example. I'd like to be able to create an array of `textfile` objects where each element corresponds to a unique text file. I'd like to be able to call `textfile` with a single argument, or *no argument at all*.

1. If I pass no argument, I'll be taken to a file select screen to select the files, and an object array will be created, one element for each file I selected.
2. If one argument is passed, I'd like the array to be created depending on what that argument was. If it was a directory path, open up the file select screen again. If it was a cell array of filepaths, create an object array of those files.

I'd like to be able to easily create more classes like `textfile` that have the same basic behaviour.

## Attempts so far

I've defined a superclass `file` to take care of behaviour common to all files. This includes things like assigning properties such as `filename` and `extension`. My other classes are all subclasses of `file`.

In the constructor for `file`, I have two input arguments. My idea was that in the relevant subclass constructors I'd call the `file` constructor. The first input argument would be the type of file, e.g. `txt`, while the second would be the argument I chose when creating the `textfile` array. For simplicity, let's say the only type of `arg` I want to be able to handle is a directory path from where to choose files from.

```
classdef textfile < file
    methods
        function textfileObject = textfile(arg)
            if nargin == 0
                arg = '';
            end
            textfileObject@file('txt',arg);
    end
end
```

The `file` constructor, depending on what `arg` is when I create `textfile` objects, generates an array of objects in accordance with [using the No Input Argument Constructor Requirement](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/class-constructor-methods.html#btn2kiy).

```
classdef file < handle
    properties
        Path
    end
    methods
        function FileObject = file(FileType,arg)
            if nargin == 2
                FileList = file.SelectFiles(FileType,arg);
                FileObject(numel(FileList),1) = file;
                for filecount = 1:numel(FileObject)
                    FileObject(filecount,1).Path = FileList{filecount};
                end
            end
        end
    end
    methods(Static)
        function FileList = SelectFiles(DirectoryPath)
             % Some selection dialogs. Returns a cell array of filepaths
        end
    end
end
```

This works when `arg` is a directory, because when the object array is initalized in `textfile` with no input argument, `arg` is set to `''` which works with the rest of the constructors.

However, I want to be able to not have any input arguments when creating `textfile` objects, but that doesn't work with the No Input Argument rules for constructors.

## The question

Is there a way to create object arrays while

1. calling a superclass constructor and
2. not using any input arguments?

I'm open to other solutions that can help with my problem of creating classes for each of my file types.

## Solution

It turns out you can call the subclass constructor from the superclass using an anonymous function. In effect, you can call the subclass constructor with no input arguments, and then generate the filenames in the superclass before calling the subclass again (recursively) with these filenames as inputs. Thanks @Suever.

The subclass constructor will simply be:

```
classdef textfile < file
    methods
        function textfileObject = textfile(varargin)
            textfileObject@file('txt',varargin{:});
        end
    end
end
```

And in the superclass:

```
classdef file < handle
    properties
        Path
    end
    methods
        function FileObject = file(FileType,varargin)

            % Subclass constructor handle
            Constructor = @(FilePath)feval(class(FileObject),FilePath);

            % No subclass arguments
            if nargin == 1
                FileList = file.SelectFiles(FileType,'');
                for a = 1:numel(FileList)
                    FileObject(a,1) = Constructor(FileList{a});
                end

            % One subclass argument
            elseif nargin == 2
                arg = varargin{1};
                if ischar(arg)
                    FileStruct = dir(arg);
                    if numel(FileStruct) == 1
                        FileObject.Path = arg;
                    end
                end

            % Too many subclass arguments
            else
                error('Subclasses of file only take one or no input arguments');
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: So you want to be prompted to select a file when you provide no inputs?

Comment: @Suever Yes, when I provide no inputs, I'd like to be prompted to select files (from the working directory by default), and then the object array will be created with each element corresponding to the files I selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this would be to call the constructor of your class recursively to generate the array of `textfile` objects.

```
classdef textfile < file

    methods
        function self = textfile(arg)
            if ~exist('arg', 'var')
                % Get list of files somehow
                [fnames, pname] = uigetfile('MultiSelect', 'on');
                filelist = fullfile(pname, fnames);

                % Call the constructor again for each file
                output = cellfun(@textfile, filelist, 'uniformoutput', 0);

                % Flatten the cell array of objects into an array of the right shape
                self = reshape([output{:}], size(filelist));
            else
                % Do default construction here
                self = self@file('txt', arg);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

If you want to implement this in the base class, you could change the recursive call to be something like the following which would call the correct subclass constructor from within the `file` superclass

```
constructor = @(varargin)feval(class(self), varargin{:});
output = cellfun(constructor, filelist, 'uniformoutput', 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That solves the problem for the `textfile` class. The only bad thing is that this means I will have to write this piece of code in every class I have for a given file type, which I why I thought it would be a good idea to have a `file` superclass to handle all that. Is there a way to use your approach when I want to use the `file` superclass constructor to handle file selection?

Comment: @spaggy I added an example of how you could do this from the super class

Comment: The problem with this is that I only want to call the superclass constructor once, but invoking the superclass constructor in the subclass cannot be done within a conditional block. This means every time the superclass constructor calls the subclass (once for each file in in the `filelist` as per the `cellfun`), the superclass constructor will be called as well....

Comment: @Jens Why only call the superclass constructor once?

Comment: The way I've written it means that the file selection happens in the superclass. I have a static method there that outputs a cell array of filenames. I did that so that I wouldn't have to repeat code for all my subclasses when it comes to file selection. I'm open to other solutions though, if this won't work with the requirement of having an empty `if nargin ==  0` block when creating object arrays.

Comment: I managed to get it to work using that anonymous function with the `feval` for the constructor. Brilliant stuff, thanks!